# Joomla correct way of routing

Tags: url, redirect, joomla-4, mvc

This is in my Controller. Currently, I am redirecting using the inherited function `setRedirect(URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO)`.

```
public function redirectTo($layout){
    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_component&view=view_name&layout=' . $layout);
    $this->redirect();
}
```

In what way can I **IMPROVE** this (if it is the correct way of redirecting)?

I am learning Joomla MVC and would like to improve my skills.

Thank you. That really clarified a lot for me. The reason I am using this method of doing it, is mainly to also pass parameters through the URL if needed.

So my next part of the function looks like this

```
public function redirectTo($layout, $id = null){
    $url = 'index.php?option=com_component&view=view_name&layout=' . 
 $layout;
    if($id){ 
        $url =  $url . "&id=" .  $id;
    }
    $this->redirect(Route::_($url));
```

Is this Okay? Or is there already a method made for this? I think I am going into a URL builder with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the URL through `Joomla\CMS\Router\Route::_()` before passing to `setRedirect()` to get the correct SEF URL since none of the involved methods do that automatically.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;

$this->setRedirect(Route::_('index.php?option=com_component&view=view_name&layout=' . $layout));
$this->redirect();
```

The rest is correct, if not somewhat unnecessary. `setRedirect()` is used to set a redirect which is performed after the controller's task has been completed. And it accepts additional parameters for setting a message and its type. Your method does not have these parameters and it performs the redirect instantly. So realistically you could remove your custom method and just call application's `redirect()` method to get the same result.

```
$this->app->redirect(Route::_('index.php?option=com_component&view=view_name&layout=' . $layout));
```

Comment: I have made some changes to the top question. If you have time, Can you give me clarity on it?